# is a kendoui typescript definition file available?

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

I'm looking for a typescript definition file for kendo ui? I checked nuget and here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped with no luck.

Comment: I found it on my machine under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q1 2013\typescript`

Comment: Too bad this was closed.  It was a decent question with a good answer.

Comment: As basarat implies, it comes with the professional edition of Kendo UI. It's not included in the core version, meaning it's also not part of the NuGet package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KendoUI ships with `kendo.all.d.ts`. A file officially maintained by the kendo team. Read more here : http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/typescript/overview

**UPDATE**

You might need to locate it in your program files `C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q1 2013\typescript`

Comment: I don't know why this is closed and why this answer is marked answered: nuget package still doesn't include definition file

Comment: Neither does the download package, although it does contain a documentation file that claims it would.

Comment: @John see update. Taken from a comment. It *used to* be easily available from the download.